# MATLAB - Integral 2 - First input argument must be a function handle

Tags: matlab, integral, function-handle

I need to use the `integral2()` function with syntax: `q = integral2(fun, xmin , xmax, ymin , ymax)`.

I've tried the commands:

```
Alphai(: , 1) = {@(x,y) Alpha(1,1)+Alpha(2,1)*x+Alpha(3,1)*y};
Alphai(: , 2) = {@(x,y) Alpha(1,2)+Alpha(2,2)*x+Alpha(3,2)*y};
Alphai(: , 3) = {@(x,y) Alpha(1,3)+Alpha(2,3)*x+Alpha(3,3)*y};
for ind = 1:3
    temp0 = integral2(Alphai(: , ind), xmin , xmax , ymin , ymax);
end
```

(already defined `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`)

But I got an error:

```
First input argument must be a function handle
```

Can someone help and explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the size of `Alphai`?

Comment: If you type `classAlphai({:,1})` and `classAlphai((:,1))`, which results do you get?

Comment: an error but someone help me, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ind = 1:3
    temp0 = integral2(Alphai{: , ind}, xmin , xmax , ymin , ymax);
end
```